# Unable to get GCM push notifcation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification msg using GCM.

I am able to successfully register my device, my device registration id that is being generated is `APA91bEHUpBYhB6yT_WO3PMgZ7p1_3_2QFzPARSgtrwk43BNlSR8t-KKi0wfIo7vWEpELS-7wndJk4D3TC2mZXivuv5SgWCGoQSRZjesNcohmCJvsWdaTBHUiT_wx8pVFtj9rtK5IFgF5KS5a5LI-X8Gv8r3YuAhjA"`

When I am sending a push msg the response I get from server is 
`{"multicast_id":6991147966445820714,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1438192656514830%358381d5f9fd7ecd"}]}`

This is the content of the GCMBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        //setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

This is the code for GCMNotification Intent Service

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        String message = extras.getString("message");

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE .equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }

                sendNotification(message);

            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        // Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        //Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

And this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample"
    android:sharedUserId="triggers.dummy.loader" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- For vibrating device -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- For receiving GCM messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- For protecting GCM messages so that only your app can receive them -->

<receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- make sure to add google-play-services_lib from  project properties->android->library -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Why am I not able to receive the push notifications? Am I doing some silly mistakes? Please help

P.S. I have posted only a snippet of the manifest, which I thought is relevant to the question.

Comment: How do you know you aren't receiving the push and that something else isn't wrong with your service?

Comment: I don't see any notification on my phone. How else do you guys check if notification is received or not?

Comment: Of course not; you haven't told your phone to display one ;)

Comment: Put something like    System.out.println("RECEIVED");     right before any of your code in the onReceive method. See if you get that far.

Comment: Take the sleeps out of your onHandleIntent message, they're an example only. I'd also recommend updating to the new GcmReceiver/GcmListenerService implementation too: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Google recommends migrating to `GCMReceiver` and `GcmListenerService`. You can try two official demo app https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android and https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm​.